# Best way to generate a migration timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate a timestamp for rails migration that I am copying into my app from an engine as part of rake task.

The following works fine, but since rails already does the same thing, i didn't know if there is a better way to do this?

```
Time.now.to_s.split(" ")[0..1].join(" ").gsub!(/\D/, "")
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
@timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Answer (score 13):

```
Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

So this might be the most meta answer I ever create on SO. The accepted answer and @mambo 's answer are correct

> `Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

But.

If you search (SO directly or Google) for "How can I create a timestamp like Rails migration file names?" it will not lead you here. However, if you start typing that as your question title, it will, mercifully, surface this answer

So, instead of asking a highly duplicate question about how I can create a generational datetime using Ruby, I've littered this answer with keywords that will hopefully be picked up by the search algorithms and answer this question for future askers like me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [timestamp.to_s(:number)](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/to_formatted_s).

There are also other formats:

```
:db            # => "2007-12-04 00:00:00"
:number        # => "20071204000000"
:short         # => "04 Dec 00:00"
:long          # => "December 04, 2007 00:00"
:long_ordinal  # => "December 4th, 2007 00:00"
:rfc822        # => "Tue, 04 Dec 2007 00:00:00 +0000"
:iso8601       # => "2007-12-04T00:00:00+00:00"
```